# Cosine simularity perfomance c#

Tags: c#, performance

I am using 2 nested SortedDictionaries to construct sparse matrix

Here is the custom simularity(sim) function I wrote . Now it has O(n^2) complexity. I looking for suggestions to improve robustness and efficiency.Thanks for any help.

```
       double 
            a = 0, b = 0,
            sqrta = 0,
            sqrtb = 0,
            sim = 0; 

        foreach (var word_i in dict)
        {
            foreach (var word_j in dict)                   
            {
                if (word_i.Key == word_j.Key) continue;

                sim=a=b=sqrta=sqrtb=0;                                   
                foreach (var term in word_j.Value.Keys)
                {
                    if (word_i.Value.ContainsKey(term))
                    {
                        word_i.Value.TryGetValue(term,out a);
                        word_j.Value.TryGetValue(term,out b);
                        sim += a * b;
                        sqrta += Math.Pow(a,2);                                
                        sqrtb += Math.Pow(b,2);
                    }

                }

                sim /= Math.Sqrt(sqrta) * Math.Sqrt(sqrtb);              

            }
        }
```

Comment: `sim` is set to 0 in every iteration of the middle loop; isn't `sim` supposed to be the output value?

Comment: Can you post the declaration of `dict`?  Seeing the type will make it easier to follow.  I am guessing its a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>`?  Also what are the keys of the inner dictionary?  And are most of them common to all words or present on only a few words each?

Comment: @S.L.Barth yes,it is. but it take too much time to find all cosines between every posible pair of 500k strings and their definitions.

Comment: @finnw  SortedDictionary<string, SortedDictionary<string, double>> dict = new SortedDictionary<string, SortedDictionary<string, double>>();

Comment: @finnw  sparse matrix is used to construct  term-document matrix[link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-term_matrix) ,where words ( as documents) are used as keys for outer SortedDictionary and unique terms in word definitions(as terms).unique terms are keys for inner SortedDictionary

Comment: Could you please, provide some small set of sample data?

Comment: Why are you using `TryGetValue` after asserting that the key does in fact exist in `word_i.Value`?  I don't think it's a performance issue as it is not going to be throwing exceptions, but still... unnecessary.  Also, if you can guarantee that the dictionaries will always contain the keys you are looking for you cut down your lookups by 1/3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are doing calculations on all values where the result depends on both loops, there isn't much that can be done about the complexity, at least not without knowing what you do with the result (which seems to be just discarded in the code shown).

There are some things that you can do in the innermost loop:

Instead of first using `Contains` and then get the value, you can use `TryGetValue` directly.

You know that `term` exists in the other collection, so you don't need `TryGetValue` for that one.

Squaring is done a lot faster by just multiplying instead of using `Math.Pow`.

```
if (word_i.Value.TryGetValue(term,out a)) {
  b = word_j.Value[term];
  sim += a * b;
  sqrta += a * a;                                
  sqrtb += b * b;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  Sim is used to find k nearest neigbors. maybe i can reduce amount of calculations because of sim(word_i,word_j)=sim(word_j,word_i). how can i modify this algorithm from sequential to run in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
public class Term
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, double> Definitions { get; set; }

    public Term(string value, Dictionary<string, double> definitions)
    {
        this.Value = value;
        this.Definitions = definitions;
    }
}

public class TermPair
{
    public Term Left { get; private set; }
    public Term Right { get; private set; }
    public double Similarity { get; private set; }

    public TermPair(Term left, Term right)
    {
        this.Left = left;
        this.Right = right;
    }

    public void CalculateSimilarity()
    {
        var sim = 0D;
        var sqrta = 0D;
        var sqrtb = 0D;

        var leftDefinitions = this.Left.Definitions;
        var rightDefinitions = this.Right.Definitions;

        foreach (var kv in leftDefinitions)
        {
            double a;
            var term = kv.Key;
            if (rightDefinitions.TryGetValue(term, out a))
            {
                var b = kv.Value;
                sim += a * b;
                sqrta += a * a;
                sqrtb += b * b;
            }
        }

        sim /= Math.Sqrt(sqrta) * Math.Sqrt(sqrtb);

        this.Similarity = sim;
    }
}
```

Use these classes like this:

```
List<Term> terms = ...

var idx = 0;
var totalTerms = terms.Count;
var pairs = new TermPair[((totalTerms - 1) * (totalTerms)) / 2];
for (var i = 0; i < totalTerms; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < totalTerms; j++)
    {
        if (i > j)
        {
            pairs[idx++] = new TermPair(terms[i], terms[j]);
        }
    }
}

foreach (var pair in pairs.AsParallel())
{
    pair.CalculateSimilarity();
}
```

I don't know your scenario but I hope this help. You can experiment with SortedDictionary & Dictionary. BTW I'm not quite sure if TryGetValue is thread safe for reading from multiple threads.